# How to create a pre-commit.com hook that runs an entry which is located in the same repository

Tags: pre-commit.com

I would like to create a repository for pre-commit.com hook with a hook that runs an entry located within this repository.

I have created a repository with a hook:

```
my-pre-commit-hook> ls -a
.pre-commit-hooks.yaml
my-script.py
```

with `.pre-commit-hooks.yaml`:

```
- id: my-check
  name: my-check
  entry: python
  args: [my-script.py]
  language: system
  files: '.*'
```

Then, from another repository I run

```
pre-commit try-repo ../my-pre-commit-hook
```

but it fails with

```
... can't open file '.../my-script.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I would expect that pre-commit.com provides some variable which I can use in `.pre-commit-hooks.yaml` to find `my-script.py`, for example

```
- id: my-check
  name: my-check
  entry: python
  args: [$PRE_COMMIT_REPO/my-script.py]
  language: system
  files: '.*'
```

I don't see much advantage of installing this script like https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks/blob/main/setup.cfg does since I have very simple script which can run from source.

Comment: what is your question exactly? have you tried [reading the docs](https://pre-commit.com) ?

Comment: I have tried to elaborate the question, thanks for a look

Comment: ok so you [did not read the docs](https://pre-commit.com/#python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Language `script` allows `entry` relative to the root of the hook repository, https://pre-commit.com/#script:

> The `entry` should be a path relative to the root of the hook repository.